# Elite Dangerous key bindings for Oculus Touch

Tags: controllers, elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons, oculus-rift, oculus-touch

I'm having trouble understanding the Oculus Touch controller bindings in Elite Dangerous.

Ignoring the Oculus and Hamburger (Menu/Pause) buttons and the analogue Hat, there are 8 buttons in total between the two controllers (A, B, X, Y, plus left and right versions of both trigger and grip), but there are 12 different values used in the original Elite Touch controller `.binds` files.

When I capture my own bindings, I only see the eight binding values for the eight buttons:

```
Buttons I can capture               Buttons only seen in .binds file
---------------------------------   ---------------------------------
Pos_OculusTouch_IndexTriggerLeft    OculusTouch_IndexTriggerLeft
Pos_OculusTouch_IndexTriggerRight   OculusTouch_IndexTriggerRight
Pos_OculusTouch_HandTriggerLeft     OculusTouch_LThumb
Pos_OculusTouch_HandTriggerRight    OculusTouch_RThumb
OculusTouch_A       OculusTouch_B
OculusTouch_X       OculusTouch_Y
```

I now have custom bindings which work for me, but I want to understand how I was supposed to be using the Oculus Touch controllers, and how I might use those binding values myself.

1. On the controller, how do I activate functions bound to  `OculusTouch_LThumb` and `OculusTouch_RThumb`?
2. On the controller, how do I activate functions bound to  `OculusTouch_IndexTriggerLeft` and `OculusTouch_IndexTriggerRight`?
3. What is the difference between `Pos_OculusTouch_IndexTriggerLeft` and `OculusTouch_IndexTriggerLeft`?
4. What is the difference between `Pos_OculusTouch_IndexTriggerRight` and `OculusTouch_IndexTriggerRight`?

#### Examples

In original Oculus Touch bindings, the `Pos_` versions are used for

```
---------------------------------   ---------------------------------
Pos_OculusTouch_IndexTriggerLeft    Pos_OculusTouch_HandTriggerRight
---------------------------------   ---------------------------------
SecondaryFire                       PrimaryFire
CyclePreviousPage                   CycleNextPage
CamZoomOut                          CamZoomIn
MultiCrewSecondaryFire              MultiCrewPrimaryFire
                                    StoreCamZoomIn & StoreCamZoomOut !                  
ExplorationFSSZoomOut               ExplorationFSSZoomIn
```

while the non `Pos_` versions are used for

```
OculusTouch_IndexTriggerLeft        OculusTouch_HandTriggerRight
---------------------------------   ---------------------------------
DecreaseSpeedButtonPartial          IncreaseSpeedButtonPartial
MoveFreeCamDownAxis                 MoveFreeCamUpAxis
```

and the `Thumb` keys are bound to

```
OculusTouch_LThumb                  OculusTouch_RThumb
---------------------------------   ---------------------------------
UseAlternateFlightValuesToggle      ToggleFreeCam
ToggleBuggyTurretButton             FixCameraRelativeToggle
MultiCrewToggleMode
FixCameraWorldToggle
```

Incidentally, it looks like `StoreCamZoomOut` on `Pos_OculusTouch_HandTriggerRight` is a mistake.

---

Note, checking suggestions in comments, I can confirm that Elite Dangerous doesn't use any position or orientation information (6DOF) from the Oculus Touch controllers at all. You can use [vJoy](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/) with [elite-vr-cockpit](https://github.com/dantman/elite-vr-cockpit) to create a virtual HOTAS, but it's very fiddly (launch *vJoy*, then *elite-vr-cockpit*, then Elite in Windows 7 compatibility mode, to force it to run in Steam VR, plus having to reboot after every vJoy configuration change) and it really didn't work well for me.

I also verified that Elite doesn't register a trigger or grip until those buttons are actually pressed - just touching them isn't enough. Nor does Elite have any binding for 'thumb in it's rest position'.

Comment: I suspect those 4 other buttons are for detecting the hand position, i.e. pointing and thumbs up.

Comment: What do you mean @MBraedley? As far as I know, ED doesn't use any 6DOF information from the Oculus Touch controllers at all. You can use [vjoy](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/) with [elite-vr-cockpit](https://github.com/dantman/elite-vr-cockpit) to create a virtual HOTAS, but it's very fiddly (launch vJoy, then elite-vr-cockpit, then ED in Steam VR mode) and it really didn't work well for me.

Comment: The controller can detect if your index finger is on the trigger and if your thumb is on the face of the controller.  That's what I think those other 4 buttons are for.  I wasn't talking about controller orientation.

Comment: I'll try out the "Index finger on trigger" rather than "index finger pulled trigger", but as I've just posted in [my answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/377937/8557), it turns out the *Thumb* binding is activated when you push down on the hat sticks.

Comment: Nope @MBraedley, the trigger isn't detected until it's actually pressed, and then it shows up as `Pos_OculusTouch_IndexTriggerLeft`, never `OculusTouch_IndexTriggerLeft`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Thumb bindings

The `OculusTouch_LThumb` and `OculusTouch_RThumb` bindings are triggered when you push down on the hat rather than rocking it in X and/or Y, so there was a 'button' that I'd missed on each controller.

Sadly, although it appears physically capable or it, the *Thumb* button doesn't work as a modifier, so you can't bind to something to pushdown *and* move in a hat direction either through analogue or digital bindings (i.e. `OculusTouch_RThumb + OculusTouch_RStickY` or `OculusTouch_LThumb + Neg_OculusTouch_LStickX` etc.). This is a real shame, as it could double the number of functions you could bind to the hat.

#### Trigger bindings

Having read through some Oculus developer documentation, I suspect that the `Pos_OculusTouch_IndexTrigger`* and `OculusTouch_IndexTrigger`*
bindings are related to the different ways Trigger (and Grip/Hand controls) can be used. They are all 'analogue' axes, but the API allows you to use them as 'analogue' positional inputs or as digital inputs, switching at 50% of travel.

This is what I suspect the two bindings are. I would guess that originally the digital version was used, but later the game switched to using the analogue binding, presumably so they could fine tune response time - trigger at 25% for faster response, or trigger at 75% to prevent accidental triggering etc.

I suspect that I can't generate `OculusTouch_IndexTrigger`* triggers myself because `Pos_OculusTouch_IndexTrigger`* is always triggered first - it will be registered at less than 50% pull, so ED never sees the 50% trigger.

#### So, why are the non `Pos_` bindings still in the `.binds` file?

I suspect that this is a throwback to the days before the `Pos_` bindings were added and that practically the `Pos_` and non `Pos_` bindings are the same, you just can't capture the non `Pos_` bindings in-game any longer.

<sup>I will have to investigate whether the trigger can be bound to analogue axes in game and have an analogue response to them, or whether you can set different trigger levels by pulling the triggers at different speeds.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Elite VR Cockpit and it is an annoying process to get working each time I want to play.

With the amount of work you're putting into this maybe it'd be easier to work with the Elite VR Cockpit dev to make a better launcher or better way to launch? Maybe launch the Elite VR Cockpit app and have a button there to properly launch Elite Dangerous directly from the Elite VR Cockpit app? Basically create a better launching workflow.  Maybe this could be done with a batch file?

Also, instead of the Windows 7 compatibility mode you can instead set the main Oculus app to run in **admin mode** only by default and it won't allow it to launch unless directly launched.  Also, I don't think you have to launch vjoy anymore once it's setup right.  Only the Elite VR Cockpit app and then Elite D. without Oculus app launching.

Comment: While a smoother launch workflow would be good, I can't imaging going back to trying to use the touch controllers now that I have a HOTAS.

As I don't need the virtual HOTAS, I would be more interested in Elite VR cockpit for it's virtual buttons, but that would need hand tracking support, as blindly picking up the touch controllers when you take your hand off the throttle or stick would be quite immersion breaking.